# Find the values of $(2\sin x-1)(\cos x+1)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

How many different value of x from 0° to 180° for the equation $(2\sin x-1)(\cos x+1) = 0$?

The solution shows that one of these is true:

$\sin x = \frac12$ and thus $x = 30^\circ$ or $120^\circ$

$\cos x = -1$ and thus $x = 180^\circ$

**Question:** Inserting the $\arcsin$ of $1/2$ will yield to $30°$, how do I get $120^\circ$? and what is that $120^\circ$, why is there $2$ value but when you substitute $\frac12$ as $x$, you'll only get $1$ value which is the $30^\circ$?

Also, when I do it inversely: $\sin(30^\circ)$ will result to 1/2 which is true as $\arcsin$ of $1/2$ is $30^\circ$. But when you do $\sin(120^\circ)$, it will be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and when you calculate the $\arcsin$ of $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, it will result to $60^\circ$ and not $120^\circ$. Why?

Comment: I think you're right.  It should be $x = 30,150$ degrees for $\sin x = 1/2$.

Comment: @D.B. Is there a term for angles like the 30 and 150 where they are both arc-sin$\frac{1}{2}$ on the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\arcsin$ returns the angle *within the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$*. In fact, there are infinitely many angles whose sine is $1/2$. Since a function can't spit out more than one number however, we define the $\arcsin$ function to return the inverse of the sine on that interval.

Anyways, the true answer here is actually $30$ degrees and $150$ degrees (with also $180$ from the cosine expression). How would you find this? Just look at our unit circle.

[image]

The part we're restricted to is the top half of the circle going counterclockwise (0 to 180). What values of $x$ spit out a y-coordinate (sine) of $1/2$?  Well, $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$ (or 30 and 150). There's your answer!

Comment: So it means that to answer these kind of questions, where there is a given range ex. (0° to 180°), I won't get the 150° on the calculator unless I am familiar or I memorized the values on the unit circle? Since on the calculator, it will only give me the first degree or radian on the unit circle. (arc sin $\frac{1}{2}$ = 30).

Comment: Or the other way around, since it is 30 degrees. It's counterpart on the left side is 180-30 = 150 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted $x=120°$ is not a solution indeed

- $(2\sin 120°-1)(\cos 120°+1)=\left(2\frac{\sqrt3}2-1\right)\left(-\frac12+1\right)\neq 0$

but

- $2\sin x-1=0 \implies x=\frac16 \pi + 2k\pi,\,x=\frac56 \pi + 2k\pi$
- $\cos x+1 = 0 \implies x=\pi + 2k\pi=(2k+1)\pi$

Answer (score 1):

If $ab = 0$, then either $a=0$ or $b=0$.
Given $(2\sin x - 1)(\cos x + 1) = 0$, we can separate these and solve separately.

So... $\ \ \ \ \ 2\sin x -1 = 0$
$\Rightarrow \sin x = \frac12 \Rightarrow x = 30^\circ, 150^\circ$
We get those two values because $\sin x$ is symmetrical across the $y$-axis.

Also... $\ \ \ \ \ \cos x + 1 = 0$
$\Rightarrow \cos x = -1 \Rightarrow x = 180^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

$0\leq \sin(x)\leq1$ in quadrants I *and* II. That is to say $\sin x$ (and $\cos x$) are stuck in a circle which is periodic. There are an infinite amount of $x$ that satisfy for example $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$, but the simplest answer is enough to suffice

Specifically, $\sin^{-1}x$ isn't a function unless its domain is restricted to $-\pi/2\leq x\leq\pi/2$

Likewise for $\cos^{-1}x$. Its not a function unless its domain is restricted to $0\leq x\leq\pi$